# HERE offline maps update from PC

Tags: here-api

I'm using HERE SDK on an Android heads up display device which only has a Bluetooth link to the internet. This internet link is therefore very slow, and somewhat unreliable.

Traffic and even live maps information seems to work pretty well, however it's impossible to update offline maps with this, they're too large and time out.

The device appears as a USB drive when plugged into pc which has the here maps offline cache folder directly visible. I've been able to test that copying the cached offline maps folder downloaded by a different here maps app on Android onto the device works to update the maps, but it's very slow and tedious.

Is is possible to update the offline maps cache from any web service / desktop app outside of the Android/iOS sdk libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to store the offline maps data into PC storage and we have to use mSDK Premium version to use the offline mode based on the offline maps data.
Additionally, the downloaded offline maps data needs to be updated when there is a new version in the HERE backend server and it is handled by HERE mSDK.